# Fuzzy search required for searching nested objects using feathers-vuex?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, feathersjs

I am using feathers-vuex in a project and am not very familiar with the rest of the feathers package. I am using this is because with the scaffolding cli, it was very easy to get started and it just works. Has been a really good experience so far. However, this also means that I do not entirely get what's going on under the hood. I am trying to use the find function to retrieve all records where a nested array contains a certain string from a mongodb. The questions are as follows:

- So far, the only option that I can think of is a fuzzy search. Is that the way to do it? Or are there other possibilities?
- Is my assumption that fuzzy search won't work because of the absence of hooks correct? Or have I misread the docs?
- Any other general way of accomplishing this?
- Does this mean that fuzzy search will not work using feathers-vuex or are there ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you got set up, I do recommend to go through the [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/readme.html) and have a look at [any of the other guides](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/readme.html).

Depending on what you picked you can also look at the [MongoDB](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongodb.html) and [Mongoose](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongoose.html) database adapter API documentation. Additionally to the [common query syntax](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html) both those adapters also support additional MongoDB queries which you can find in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).

If you look at the MongoDB [documentation on how to query for arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/) you can see that querying for a value in an array can be done similar to this:

```
async function run() {
  await app.service('myservice').create({
    name: 'first',
    test: [ 'one', 'two' ]
  });

  await app.service('myservice').create({
    name: 'second',
    test: [ 'two', 'three' ]
  });

  let results = await app.service('myservice').find({
    query: { test: 'two' }
  });

  console.log(results) // will log `first` and `second`

  result = await app.service('myservice').find({
    query: { test: 'one' }
  });

  console.log(results) // will log only `first`
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I missed that you could also use mongo syntax. Thanks!